# Trouble in Netlify deployment for an rbind blog

Tags: blogdown, netlify

As a new year resolution, I am trying to write a few more posts for my blog this year. However, I am having trouble in publishing them using `Netlify`. I am getting the following message when I try to deploy

```
4:46:43 PM: Build ready to start
4:46:44 PM: build-image version: 53a2d5fe9ca22a80747972bf7a83d93509ec503c
4:46:44 PM: buildbot version: 4011bc275ed1e45f93e758dff0bce4fda2a3c46f
4:46:45 PM: Fetching cached dependencies
4:46:45 PM: Starting to download cache of 254.7KB
4:46:45 PM: Finished downloading cache in 91.447642ms
4:46:45 PM: Starting to extract cache
4:46:45 PM: Failed to fetch cache, continuing with build
4:46:45 PM: Starting to prepare the repo for build
4:46:45 PM: git ref refs/heads/master does not exist or you do not have permission
4:46:45 PM: Failing build: Failed to prepare repo
4:46:45 PM: failed during stage 'preparing repo': git ref refs/heads/master does not exist
4:46:45 PM: Finished processing build request in 754.802626ms
```

I noticed that in the `netlify` `Build Settings`, there is `base directory` option which is not set up for my blog. I looked at the `blogdown` documentation on deployment and it looks they are also based on older version of `netlify` (https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/netlify.html) and do not mention the `base directory` option.

I have also changed `HUGO_VERSION` to `0.53` in `Build Environment variables` to match the latest version. I hope that is not the issue.

Can anyone help me in resolving this issue, specifically what to set the `Base directory` for my site.

The `github` repo for the files for my blog is at https://github.com/sn248/sn248.github.io

and the site (with minimal content) is at https://sn248.rbind.io/

Also, the new post is added and shows up as expected locally i.e., when I use `blogdown::serve_site()`.

Thank you

Comment: Hi, I forked your repo(https://github.com/tcgriffith/sn248.github.io) and tried to deploy it through netlify. The site is deployed successfully: `https://wonderful-ride-bf1b3e.netlify.com/`. Could you double check and try it again?

Comment: thank you. yes, I was able to get the `*.netlify.com` to work too .. but now I am having issues pointing it to `sn248.rbind.io`

Comment: hi @SN248, You should open an issue in this repo https://github.com/rbind/support/issues and let the admin direct the cname to your netlify subdomain, then you can set up the rbind domain on netlify.

Comment: Thanks, I will follow your suggestion.